# Twitter Log in Using OAuth in Xcode

Tags: twitter, oauth, ios4

I am Logging into the twitter account using Oauth.I have also a logout button in my ios app.After successfully logging into my twitter .i want to log in as a new user in twitter by this logout button. i used the same code for login .but it is not working .Please help  me